# Can I search for which admin made a change to a Jira project (not an issue)?

Tags: jira, jql

One of our admins updated the project’s icon in project settings.

I would like to know who did it (for reasons I would like to keep confidential).

Can I, a non-admin, see this information in a log or via JQL somehow?